# Redirect from https to http in Nginx for some urls

Tags: nginx, ssl, drupal

I have an Nginx configuration with ssl installed/enabled, and everything works fine, but I need to disable https on certain urls. I have tried to achieve this but I'm stuck at the redirect loop between https to http and back. Please see my configs in the image below, any help will be appreciated.

```
server {
   listen         80 default_server;
   listen    [::]:80 default_server;
   server_name    server_domain.com www.server_domain.com;
   root   /var/www/html/path_to_app_folder;
   index  index.php index.html index.htm;
   listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/server_domain/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/server_domain/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

   location ~ ^(/prime.*) {
    #default_type text/html;
    #return 200 http://$server_name$request_uri;
      return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
   }
```

}

[image: config image]

Comment: What do you mean by URL? Is a URL = URI. Means server.com/test = HTTPS, server.com/something = HTTP?? So as far as I know certbot will automatically redirect an configured site to https.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$scheme`

```
if ($scheme = https) {
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: This gives a 404 response after saving. The comment code #default_type text/html;
    #return 200 http://$server_name$request_uri; works fine, but the redirect doesn't

Comment: Check the access log  and error log to see the reason.

Comment: getting closer, the redirect rule adds /prime/ in the root path (root   /var/www/html/path_to_app_folder; ) , the error on the log file indicates ""/var/www/html/path_to_app_folder/prime/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), "

Comment: So where is your `index.php`

Comment: "/var/www/html/path_to_app_folder/prime/index.php" on this path without the prime folder